# normalvariate with bounds?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, normal-distribution

Is it possible to use python's functions in `random` module like `normalvariate` or `gammavariate`, but with some lower and/or upper bounds?. In short, I'm looking if there is a more efficient way to do this:

```
temp = normalvariate(mu, sigma)
while not (lower_bound <= temp <= upper_bound):
    temp = normalvariate(mu, sigma)
do_something(temp)
```

Comment: There's nothing like this built into Python. If you can use numpy, [`scipy.stats.truncnorm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html) is probably what you want. If not, you'll need a third-party library. Unfortunately, the first one I found, [`rtnorm`](https://github.com/classner/py-rtnorm), requires numpy… but you could borrow the code, or reimplement [the same algorithm](http://miv.u-strasbg.fr/mazet/rtnorm/).

Comment: Also see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) for some discussion on different algorithms to simulate a truncated normal distribution.

Comment: @abarnert great, I will look at it thanks!

Comment: If you end up implementing something yourself, or adapting `rtnorm` to not rely on numpy, you should ideally come back here and answer your own question and accept it. If you decide to just switch to numpy/scipy and use `truncnorm` out of the box, there’s probably a dup with solid example code we can link this question to instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided that for the context applied, it's not worth to require such a heavy module as scipy or numpy, so I just did what I posted on my question, until I find something efficient and light weight.